# How do we use Watchkit Touch Events?

Tags: ios, events, touchesmoved, watchkit

I wanna use touch events in my app. I know gesture recognisers can not be used in watchKit. Is it possible to use functions like touchesBegan, touchesMove etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little late to the party, but it's possible to use SceneKit with WatchKit and SceneKit allows you to add gesture handlers.  Please see the Apple example project here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/WatchPuzzle/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017284-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Edit: Looks like Tap, Swipe, Long Press and Pan gesture handles can be added to any view added to the InterfaceController.

Answer (score 6):

Apple Watch app uses [WatchKit framework.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WatchKit_framework/index.html) UIKit events are not applicable here.

Alternate is to use forced touch event which triggers [Context Menu](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/Menus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH15-SW1) (if available)

> Instead of just tapping items on the screen, pressing the screen with a small amount of force activates the context menu (if any) associated with the current interface controller.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such an api like "touchesBegan" or "touchesMove".

The only thing you can do to respond to a button event is to use IBAction.