# Xcode 7.3 - Swift - Expected Declaration - Apple Watch App

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos

My watch app will be a random number generator.

I get two error messages:

> Expected declaration, use of undeclared type 'UIEVENT' and
>    use of undeclared type 'UILABEL'

I think there is something wrong with the label but I am not sure.

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    @IBAction func ButtonTapped() {
    }

    @IBOutlet var numberLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    }

    var randomNumber = String(arc4random_uniform(5))

    NumberLabel.setText(randomnumber)
    var NumberLabel : UILabel = UILabel()

}
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Why is supposed to trigger the `NumberLabel.setText(randomnumber)` code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  What makes you think there's something wrong?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! FYI, you can [edit] your question to add more information to it, instead of leaving those details in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use iOS classes in a watchOS app.

On iOS, UIKit has `UILabel` and `UIEvent`.

On watchOS, WatchKit has `WKInterfaceLabel`. [There are no touch events for watchOS.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27183746/4151918)

```
NumberLabel.setText(randomnumber)
var NumberLabel : UILabel = UILabel()
```

should be

```
numberLabel.setText(random number)
```

Also, I think you meant the code to generate a new random number to be inside `awakeWithContext:` or `buttonTapped()`.

*The convention is for types to start with an uppercase letter, while methods, functions, and properties start with a lowercase letter.*