# How to detect touch inputs in SKScene on watchOS SpriteKit?

Tags: swiftui, sprite-kit, watchos

I'm trying to display a SKScene inside SwiftUI on watchOS and detect touch events.

```
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            SpriteView(scene: GameScene(size: reader.size))
                .focusable()
        }
    }
```

Works fine, now i want to detect touches in the scene, but the method touchesBegan is not available in watchOS. How do i accomplish this?

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        <#code#>
    }
```

I looked at the documentation which says something about WKTapGestureRecognizer but im not sure how to use this since i'm using SwiftUI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do we use Watchkit Touch Events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183746/how-do-we-use-watchkit-touch-events)

Comment: No, I don't think so. I'm specifically looking at capturing touch events in SKScene